# Small sample MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Is there a go-to reference for the effect of small samples on MLE estimates? Specifically the effect on the parameter distribution. i.e. should we switch to something like a *t*-distribution with fewer degrees of freedom rather then a normal for the distribution of the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

when you use MLE, your best estimate is subject to an error term which indicates the uncertainty in your estimate. Therefore you can write your estimate like this:

$\mu = \mu_{MLE} \pm e$

where $\mu_{MLE}$ is your MLE estimate for $\mu$ and $e$ is the uncertainty in estimating $\mu$. Now there are two scenarios for $e$: first, if you know the standard deviation $\sigma$ of your measurments in advance, then you have:

\begin{equation}
\mu = \mu_{MLE} \pm \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{equation}

second, when you don't know $\sigma$ and you estimating it from the data:

\begin{equation}
\mu = \mu_{MLE} \pm \frac{Q}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{equation}

where,

\begin{equation}
Q^2 = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i - \mu) ^2
\end{equation}

In all these cases, your uncertainty is proportional to the inverse of square root of your sample size $N$. As a rule of thumb, smaller the sample size, larger your uncertainty. 
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: To add to the answer, a practical consideration is the option to treat `e` as an unknown parameter to be fitted. I'm not saying that this is the best way (nor am I saying it isn't the best), but I do think it is an option. Right? That being said, I think the question concerns "is there a general pattern in bias/ precision that is introduced due to small samples?", and if 'yes', what is the reference. To this, I do not know the answer, but I know specific studies exist.

Comment: Interested in the distribution not just the standard deviation. As the sample size increases the distribution of the MLE estimate tends to be normal.  My question is around what is the distribution if we have small samples.

Comment: There is no general answer to the question "what will be the distribution in small samples".  Every case must be treated as special! That is the grand simplification from large sample asymptotics, that we get general answers with weak assumptions.